# Отправить data каждого div

Tags: php, ajax, json, асинхронность

есть несколько div c #schedule_slots на странице, у них есть атрибут например data-offer-id, необходимо при загрузке страницы отправлять Ajax каждый data-offer-id
Далее получать данные json и подставлять в нужные div

Сам ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/url',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'offer_id': '195'},
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        // loader_add
        html = '<div id="item-loader" style="position:absolute; z-index: 999; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5); left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100"><div class="spinner-grow text-primary my-auto" style="width: 5rem;height: 5rem;" role="status"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div></div></div>';

        $('#schedule_slots').css('position', 'relative');
        $('#schedule_slots').append(html);
    },      
    success: function(json) {

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $('#schedule_slots').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-booking small  mr-2 mb-2 p-1" style="width: 66px;">'+ json[i]['time'] +'</button>');
            }


        // loader_remove
        $('#item-loader').remove();
    }
});
```

Не понимаю как именно написать скрипт для того чтобы он отправлял каждый

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что на странице не может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым ID?

Comment: как минимум изменить id на class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что нужно сделать, это в html-коде заменить `id="schedule_slots"` на `class="schedule_slots"`.

Далее проходим по всем `.schedule_slots` с помощью метода `each`, получаем данные из `data` и отправляем запрос:

```
$('.schedule_slots').each(function(){
    let $schedule_slot = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'offer_id': $schedule_slot.data('offer-id')},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // loader_add
            html = '<div id="item-loader" style="position:absolute; z-index: 999; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5); left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100"><div class="spinner-grow text-primary my-auto" style="width: 5rem;height: 5rem;" role="status"><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div></div></div>';

            $schedule_slot.css('position', 'relative');
            $schedule_slot.append(html);
        },      
        success: function(json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $schedule_slot.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-booking small  mr-2 mb-2 p-1" style="width: 66px;">'+ json[i]['time'] +'</button>');
            }

            // loader_remove
            $('#item-loader').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Он очень помог, а если мне нужно получить слоты одного div, то писать новую функцию для этого?

Comment: Да, это должен быть другой код. Отметьте мой ответ решением, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. `#schedule_slots` нельзя несколько одинаковых id иметь на одной странице. Браузер на такое ругается. Пользуйтесь классами для пометки каких-либо элементов на странице, например `js-shedule-slots`. Тогда и селектор поменяется на '.js-shedule-slots'.
2. Как пытаетесь собирать информацию с data атрибутов? В чем там загвоздка?